# Finding the decimal value of numbers in Two's and One's Complement

Tags: decimal, complement

I want to turn a negative float number into decimal one but I dont know how to do it.
for example I got the number 101.1011 and I need to find the decimal value in Two's complement ( the answer supposed to be -2.3125) and in One's complement (-2.25)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you know what binary numbers represent in general.
For Two's complement you just have to know that the left-most bit is also telling you if the number is negative or positive.

So for the Two's complement of your example it would be:
-(2<sup>2</sup>) + 2<sup>0</sup> = -4 + 1 = -3 for the integer part (left-side of the decimal point) and 2<sup>-1</sup> + 2<sup>-3</sup> + 2<sup>-4</sup> = 0.5 + 0.125 + 0.0625 = 0.6875.
So, you get -3 + 0.6875 = -2.3125.

For One's complement you look at the left-most bit, that tells you it is a negative number. So you invert every bit and take the left-most bit as sign-bit (ignore its value). Then you compute it as a normal binary number.

For your example this would be:
101.1011 -> -10.0100 = -(2<sup>1</sup>) + 2<sup>-2</sup> = -2.25